# electrolysis in aqueous solution. Why is hydroxide discharged at the anode when no halide ions are present

Tags: electrolysis

Why are hydroxide Ions discharged when halide ions aren’t present in aqueous solution during electrolysis

Comment: Please see this link: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/19871/79678